# How to compare two tables in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two identical tables:

```
A :   id1, id2, qty, unit
B:    id1, id2, qty, unit
```

The set of `(id1,id2)` is identifying each row and it can appear only once in each table.

I have `140` rows in table `A` and `141 rows` in table `B`.
I would like to find all the keys (id1,id2) that are not appearing in both tables. There is 1 for sure but there can't be more (for example if each table has whole different data).

I wrote this query:

```
(TABLE a EXCEPT TABLE b)
UNION ALL
(TABLE b EXCEPT TABLE a) ;
```

But it's not working. It compares the whole table where I don't care if `qty` or `unit` are different, I only care about `id1,id2`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use a full outer join:

```
 select a.*,b.* 
 from a full outer join b 
   on a.id1=b.id1 and a.id2=b.id2
```

this show both tables side by side. with gaps where there is an unmatched row.

```
 select a.*,b.* 
 from a full outer join b 
   on a.id1=b.id1 and a.id2=b.id2
   where a.id1 is null or b.id1 is null;
```

that will only show unmatched rows.

or you can use not in

```
select * from a 
  where (id1,id2) not in
   ( select id1,id2 from b )
```

that will show rows from a not matched by b.

or the same result using a join

```
select a.* 
  from a left outer join b 
  on a.id1=b.id1 and a.id2=b.id2
  where b.id1 is null
```

sometimes the join is faster than the "not in"

Comment: what if row appears in b but not in a? What is the purpose of NULLs in the 2nd query?

Comment: the fist two list resuls from both tables, the second two onlt from table a, you can use union to include the complementart query to list the results from table b. the `is null`s  exclude the rows that contain a record from both tables.

Comment: What if rows coexist in two tables, but have different values on some columns?

Comment: the orifginal question was looking only at id1,id2 as the primary key on both tables.

Comment: @PawełSopel but iy you want to compare whole rows use `a=b` instead of `a.id=b.id`,  but something different using  `EXCEPT` might be better there.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of using EXCEPT to see what records are different.  Reverse the select statements to see what is different. a except s / then s except a

```
SELECT
a.address_entrytype,
a.address_street,
a.address_city,
a.address_state,
a.address_postal_code,
a.company_id


FROM
prospects.address a  

except 

SELECT
s.address_entrytype,
s.address_street,
s.address_city,
s.address_state,
s.address_postal_code,
s.company_id

FROM
prospects.address_short s
```